# Unable to run emacs

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I have been running $ emacs &, however, I keep getting " Display localhost:0/0 unavailable, simulating -nw". Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: What is the value of your DISPLAY environment variable? It normal value is `DISPLAY=:0`.

Answer (score 0):

The `DISPLAY` variable contains the "location" of the X server an X client (i.e., a graphical application) is supposed to connect to. From the terminal you run `emacs`, the variable is `localhost:0.0` or something similar, meaning a locally running X server on the computer the shell is running.

For some reason this connection isn't available when `emacs` tries to actually connect to it. So it decides to run in "text mode" (`-nw`, no windows) instead.

If you want to find out **why** the X server is not available, you must edit the question, tell us what system you execute this command on, if an X server is running there or not, and how you set your `DISPLAY` variable when you login, and how you login to that shell in the first place.